# Manually override shipping rate in admin

Tags: admin, shipping, overrides, shipping-methods

Here is an unusual problem that I'm struggling with. I looked at different extensions and could not find one that do what I need. I need to be able to manually override shipping price for selected method in admin. There is plenty extensions allowing to enter freehand shipping method and price, but in this case I need to be able to override just the price of one of the standard method. E.g. customer calls and we want to give UPS Ground shipping for $5, so I need to be able to manually enter $5 as rate but I need to have the ups_GND as shipping method in the db. Any pointers where to start coding something like this?

Comment: Will the edit order option work for you? If yes, you can use some extension like "shipping rules" to override the shipping cost.

Comment: What version are you working on, you will need to over ride ups model in this case

Answer (score 1):

You can use a flat price shipping associated with a customer group. 
You will need to code an extension to apply/activate this method to only one customer group, but it might actually work.

Comment: That is the problem - this has to completely independent of any other entries in the admin panel. We are using customer groups for other purposes and we need to be able to override shipping price for customers from any group.